# Removing Sprites from vector in sfml 2.1

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm trying to remove sprites from a vector, but to no avail and I don't know what's wrong(VS 2010 with SFML 2.1). It simply doesn't compile. Any tips appreciated.

Its this line, that seems problematic:

`SpriteVector.erase(std::remove(SpriteVector.begin(), SpriteVector.end(), SpriteIt), SpriteVector.end());`

Full code:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow mMainWindow(sf::VideoMode(1200, 900), "Map");
    mMainWindow.setFramerateLimit(60);

    sf::RectangleShape rect;
    rect.setSize(sf::Vector2f(1500, 500));
    sf::Texture unittexture;
    unittexture.loadFromFile("sprite.png");

    std::vector<sf::Sprite> SpriteVector;
    std::vector<sf::Sprite>::iterator SpriteIt;

    while (mMainWindow.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (mMainWindow.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            {
                mMainWindow.close();
            }
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed && event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::A)   
            {
                sf::Sprite newSprite;
                newSprite.setTexture(unittexture);
                newSprite.setPosition(mMainWindow.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Vector2i(sf::Mouse::getPosition(mMainWindow).x-50,sf::Mouse::getPosition(mMainWindow).y-50))); 
                SpriteVector.push_back(newSprite);
            }
            else if (event.type == sf::Event::MouseButtonPressed && event.mouseButton.button == sf::Mouse::Right)
                    {
                    //  sf::Vector2f mousecoords(mMainWindow.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Vector2i(event.mouseButton.x, event.mouseButton.y)));     
                    //  SpriteVector.remove_if([=](sf::Sprite newSprite){return newSprite.getGlobalBounds().contains(mousecoords); });     //example code that would work with a list

                        SpriteVector.erase(std::remove(SpriteVector.begin(), SpriteVector.end(), SpriteIt), SpriteVector.end());           // This doesn't work and I don't know why.
                    }
        }   
    mMainWindow.clear();
    mMainWindow.draw(rect);

        for(auto &SpriteIt = SpriteVector.begin();SpriteIt != SpriteVector.end();++SpriteIt)
        {
            mMainWindow.draw(*SpriteIt);
        }
        mMainWindow.display();


    }

    return 0;
}
```

Error log:

```
bei Anpassung der Argumentliste '(sf::Sprite, const std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>)'
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<sf::Sprite,std::allocator<sf::Sprite>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 10.0\vc\include\algorithm(1829): Siehe Verweis auf die Instanziierung der gerade kompilierten Funktions-template "_FwdIt std::_Remove<sf::Sprite*,_Ty>(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &)".
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _FwdIt=sf::Sprite *,
1>              _Ty=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<sf::Sprite,std::allocator<sf::Sprite>>>
1>          ]
1>          c:\users\bogdan\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\spielkarte bev\sfmltest\main.cpp(40): Siehe Verweis auf die Instanziierung der gerade kompilierten Funktions-template "_FwdIt std::remove<std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>,std::_Vector_iterator<_Myvec>>(_FwdIt,_FwdIt,const _Ty &)".
1>          with
1>          [
1>              _FwdIt=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<sf::Sprite,std::allocator<sf::Sprite>>>,
1>              _Myvec=std::_Vector_val<sf::Sprite,std::allocator<sf::Sprite>>,
1>              _Ty=std::_Vector_iterator<std::_Vector_val<sf::Sprite,std::allocator<sf::Sprite>>>
1>          ]
```

Comment: When posting questions regarding build errors, please include the complete and unedited error log in the question. Please edit your question to include them, and also please indicate where in the included source the errors are.

Comment: The error log is in a foreign language, cryptic and relatively long. Should I really post it?

Comment: You can temporarily change language to English, build to get the errors, and then change back.

Comment: Hmm, I think, that's impossible, because the distributions are language-based and I haven't got the english one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're passing a type, `SpriteIt`, as the last argument to `remove` instead of the value you want removed from the container.