# How to draw SFML shapes stored in a vector

Tags: c++, vector, draw, sfml, shapes

I'm making a copy of the game "Asteroids" using SFML.

To store all my asteroids I use a `std::vector<sf::ConvexShape>` vector, which stores all of the asteroid shapes. The problem is drawing the shapes from the vector. I looked at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24971814/removing-sprites-from-vector-in-sfml-2-1) and saw that I could use an iterator to draw my shapes (I know he used sprites in that post but I presume it makes no difference if I were to use shapes.)

So I tried that:

```
for(std::vector<sf::ConvexShape>::iterator it=allShapes.begin();it!= allShapes.end(); ++it){
    window.draw(*it);
}
```

And that throws an exception, terminating my program.
FYI: above, `allShapes` contains `sf::ConvexShape` shapes.

**So the question is:** How do I draw shapes that I store in a vector?

Full sauce:

```
using namespace std;

class asteroid{
public:
    sf::Vector2f pos;
    double angle;
    void update(sf::Vector2f);
    void create(std::vector<sf::ConvexShape>);
};
/* Will be implemented later
void asteroid::update(sf::Vector2f a){
    pos += a;
};
*/
void asteroid::create(std::vector<sf::ConvexShape> a){
    cout << "Creating..." << endl;
    a.push_back(sf::ConvexShape()); //New asteroid SHAPE
    std::vector<sf::ConvexShape>::iterator tempIt = a.end();
    tempIt->setPointCount(4);

    for(int i = 0; i < tempIt->getPointCount()+1; i++){ //Drawing asteroid
        tempIt->setPoint(i, sf::Vector2f(i*100, i*100));
    }
    tempIt->setFillColor(sf::Color::White);
    cout << "Done!" << endl;
};

int main()
{
    // Init //
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");

    std::vector<sf::ConvexShape> allShapes; //List of all asteroid SHAPES
    std::vector<asteroid> allAsteroids; //List of asteroid CLASS OBJECTS

    allAsteroids.push_back(asteroid()); //New asteroid CLASS OBJECT

    for(std::vector<asteroid>::iterator it = allAsteroids.begin(); it != allAsteroids.end(); ++it){ //Creating asteroids
        it->create(allShapes);
    }


    // Loop //
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        // Event //
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        // Display //
        window.clear();
        for(std::vector<sf::ConvexShape>::iterator it = allShapes.begin(); it != allShapes.end(); ++it){
            window.draw(*it);
        }
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: For one, you cannot dereference `a.end();`. And you're doing weird, weird things in your code.

Comment: could I derefrence it by `a.end()-1;`?
EDIT: or rather `a.rbegin();`

Comment: What do you mean by weird?

Comment: You're passing `a` by value, and not using `this` instance of `asteroid` in `asteroid::create`. Non-static member functions are supposed to do something with the object.

Comment: Now I realize I didn't need to have the `create` void as a member of the `asteroid` class and changed that, now it stands on its own. Also, I don't know of any other way of passing `a` other than a value, does it make a difference?

Comment: *And that throws an exception* - what exception?

Comment: I'm not sure, at first it tells me it triggered a break point. If I click continue it gives me this: 

>Unhandled exception at 0x77D0ED0B (ntdll.dll) in SFML testing.exe: 0xC0000374: A heap has been corrupted (parameters: 0x77D44270). 

I don't know what to make of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a few problems here...

First:

```
std::vector<sf::ConvexShape>::iterator tempIt = a.end();
tempIt->setPointCount(4);
```

`end()` does NOT give you an iterator to the last element in the vector - it gives you an iterator to the "element" just past it, and is used for bounds checking (e.g. in a for loop). In other words it does not point to valid data, so the second line is invalid. There are many approaches you could use here; the following two are "most correct" though:

```
//with iterators using a.end() - 1
std::vector<sf::ConvexShape>::iterator tempIt = a.end() - 1;
tempIt->setPointCount(4);

//with back, accessing the element directly
a.back().setPointCount(4);
```

Secondly:

```
for(int i = 0; i < tempIt->getPointCount()+1; i++)
```

The asteroid has four points, so `getPointCount()+1` = 5. This means that the loop executes for i = 0, 1, 2, 3, and 4 - one too many times.

Thirdly:

```
tempIt->setPoint(i, sf::Vector2f(i*100, i*100));
```

This line runs once for each i. Assuming you make the change above, this results in the points  (0,0), (100, 100), (200, 200), and (300, 300). This is a line, not a convex shape. You will need to revise your formula. Setting the points directly is also a fine option, as there are only 4 to set.

You also may want to pass the vector by reference to avoid making any unnecessary copies:

```
void create(std::vector<sf::ConvexShape>& a){
//...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Conduit, I'm still new to c++ in general so this was an eye opener. Also just to clarify, the `tempIt->setPoint(i, sf::Vector2f(i*100, i*100));` is just a test line, I have a formula that creates convex shapes properly in another file.

Comment: @Lolechi I figured that might be the case, but thought I might as well include it with the rest. If you need resources for learning C++ basics [this is where I started](http://www.learncpp.com/) - I can not recommend it highly enough. Consider reading the section about the Standard Template Library. Good luck!